# Autocorrection and Suggestion for custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard, uilexicon, uitextchecker

I want to add Autocorrection and Suggestion to my custom keyboard.

There are already [several similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919756/4541800) on Stack, but there is only said about `UILexicon` which as I understood is only used to  get user's shortcuts and that there is no way to acces Apple Autocorrection and Suggestion library.

I also saw [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333723/having-trouble-with-uitextchecker-xcode-iphone) regarding  `UITextChecker` but don't know if it has an access to Apple's native sugesstion library?

May be there are some new classes for that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use four different systems for my keyboard:

1. I have a list of the top 30,000 or so words, ranked in order of the most used to the least used. You can pay for lists, I just got a free one of about 42,000 and edited it down a lot.
2. guessesForWordRange is provided by Apple. It will guess words that are close to what you have typed. It does a fairly good job, but I had to filter out some things. The top guess sometimes has quotation marks around it, but other then that it works great.
3. completionsForPartialWordRange is also provided by Apple. It will return completed words, but in alphabetical order, not ranked by usage. Not much good on it's own, but is a great supplement to 1 and 2. (if this worked correctly #1 wouldn't be needed)
4. Special cases. Mainly for contractions. When someone types didnt, I wanted it to auto choose didn't. So I have almost all contractions specifically programmed in.

So my word suggestions and autocorrection aren't perfect, but it does a decent job.

Hope this helps.

Edit: As of iOS 16 it seems completionsForPartialWordRange is working correctly, so having your own list of words shouldn't be needed anymore.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, thanks! I was curious when you mentioned the top 30k words, whether these are commonly misspelled words, or simply commonly used English words.

Comment: I just did the top 30k words because my app uses autocomplete. I used the guessesForWordInRange for misspelled words.

Comment: I have a small question, In my custom keyboard, how can I detect the most recent word typed? Thanks!

Comment: @BashirSidani - This is how I did it
`let proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
var wordsBeingTyped = NSString()
wordsBeingTyped = proxy.documentContextBeforeInput! as NSString
let range = NSMakeRange(0, (wordsBeingTyped).length)
wordsBeingTyped.enumerateSubstrings(in: range, options: NSString.EnumerationOptions.byWords) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
                self.lastWord = substring!`

Comment: var arrPredictive = [String]()
        let textChecker = UITextChecker()
        let misspelledWord = strText
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: misspelledWord.utf16.count)
        let completions = textChecker.completions(forPartialWordRange: range, in: misspelledWord, language: "en")
        arrPredictive.removeAll()
        if let completions = completions {
            for word in completions {
                arrPredictive.append(word)
                print("Predtive --->",word)
            }
            print("Predtive Array->",arrPredictive)
        }